# How to create native Android switches on Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-native

The default switch for stock Android looks as follows:

[image]

However, on some Android flavors such as MIUI, the switch looks like this in their native apps:

[image]

How can I achieve this native behavior for all Android flavors (Samsung, MIUI, Huawei, Sony, etc.) with Flutter?

Comment: I could create a unique theme for each Android flavor but is there maybe a better method available provided by Flutter?

Comment: you would need to write all of them by yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below snippet for Switch Button like Android:

```
Flexible(
        child: SwitchListTile(
                                title: const Text(
                                    '<Put Your Text>',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                value: isSwitch,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isSwitch = value;
                                  });
                                },
                                activeColor: Colors.white,
                                activeTrackColor:
                                    CustomColors.switchActiveColor,
                                inactiveThumbColor:
                                    CustomColors.switchDisableCircleColor,
                                inactiveTrackColor:
                                    CustomColors.switchDisableColor,
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              ),
                              flex: 1)
```

isSwitch is bool flag to manage on/off

Comment: This means that I have to create this for each flavor myself?

Comment: Yes, @Myzel394. As per your need, you can customize it.